# How to change locale of Activity in Android App programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-configchanges

I want to change my language in App (or set it from saved variable in SQLite database). It is working, but its behavior is really weird. If I open my app it will change `Locale` in `onCreate` but if I start new activity from `MainActivity`, that new Activity (it is brand new after app start - never stopped/paused before) is in default system language. If I exit this Activity and start Intent again, it is suddenly in saved language. Only first start is loading system language.

I have my abstract class for Activity which is extending all of my Activities in my App.

Code:

```
lateinit var app: App

override val coroutineContext = Job()

override fun onCreate(si: Bundle?) {
    app = application as App
    LocaleHelper.changeLocale(this, app.getSavedLanguage())
    super.onCreate(si)
}

class LocaleHelper {

companion object{
    fun changeLocale(context: Context, lang: String){
        val newLocale = Locale(lang)
        Locale.setDefault(newLocale)
        val res = context.resources
        val conf = res.configuration
        conf.setLocale(newLocale)
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.displayMetrics)
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the language in every Activity, I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve but this is how I can handle localization in my Apps

first, create a class to handle localization and return `ContextThemeWrapper` to Create a new context wrapper with the specified theme.

```
class Localization(base: Context) : ContextThemeWrapper(base, R.style.AppTheme) {
    companion object {

        fun wrap(context: Context, language: String): ContextThemeWrapper {
            var ctx = context
            val config = context.resources.configuration

            if (language != "" || language != "en")
                )
            ) {
                val locale = Locale(language)
                Locale.setDefault(locale)
                //Using setLocale b/c my version is > 17
                config.setLocale(locale)
                // Used setLayoutDirection for RTL and LTR
                config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
                ctx = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
            }

            //Save the selected language in shared Preference,
            //context.putString("my_lang", language)

            return Localization(ctx)
        }
  }
```

then call that `wrap` function when you need to change the language

```
wrap(this, "en")
```

use sharedPreference when you are changing language and getting the current language
in your activities.
Override attachBaseContext and call `wrap` function with the current language

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(
            wrap(
                newBase,
                "en"
            )
        )

    }
```

> Note: my recommendation is to use `sharedPreference` for Localization

Comment: This is a reason why i didnt want do do ContextWrapper, because in attachbaseContext I dont have my application instance available - i cant access its data about language

Comment: Also cant use this, because it will crash on Firebase Cloud Messaging. This modified context is not compatible with Firebase services

Comment: I didn't use Firebase but thank you for letting me know it